# Record the set in the diagram using operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematica

Can you help me

Record the set in the diagram using operations

I will be happy for your help.

Chart images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHVRC.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Try it piece by piece.